# How can I incorporate Chosen into my React project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jquery-chosen

I want to use a jquery plugin [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in my project. I installed jQuery and Chosen via npm:

```
npm i jquery chosen-js -S
```

Both libraries are now in my node_modules folder. Unfortunately I keep getting an error: `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` when the app tries to compile.

Here is where I make a call to the Chosen library:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import $ from "jquery";
import "chosen-js/chosen.css";
import "chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.refs.list).chosen();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select ref="list">
        <option>vanilla</option>
        <option>chocolate</option>
        <option>strawberry</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

ReactDom.render(, document.getElementById("app"));

Here's a pic of the error:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [react-chosen](https://github.com/chenglou/react-chosen) wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on Udemy as well.
If you do really wanna take your react career seriously, you need to eventually quit using jQuery.

I have made very complex select components, ones that even use data from APIs, using react-select. I would suggest using React Select for all your selection needs, it's a powerhouse component and will change your life.

If you still find it imperative to use chosen.js, then edit 'chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js' and add import statements or require statements like

```
import jQuery from 'jquery' // or
const jQuery = require('jquery');
```

so that the reference error goes away. However, if you consider a serious front end career you need to understand that jQuery is dead, and serious apps will not use both react and jquery for the simple question of bloating and redundancy

Answer (score 0):

don't change sources, better write in your component

```
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

before chosen-js imports