# Adding a jQuery plugin is not working in a React app; "TypeError: this.$el.chosen is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, jquery-plugins

I am learning React and am following [integrating other Libraries chapter](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html). I tried the same they have suggested, but I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: this.$el.chosen is not a function
Chosen.componentDidMount
src/App.js:18

  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
>   this.$el.chosen();
  }
```

The React website provides [an example CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/qmqeQx?editors=0010) where they have added the jQuery and chosen plugin *.js* files in dependencies. I have added jQuery and chosen the library *.js* file in **index.html** and also added jQuery using `npm install jquery --save`, so that it can be imported in **App.js**.

#### File *index.html*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### File *App.js*

```javascript
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import $ from 'jquery';

class Chosen extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.chosen();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$el.chosen('destroy');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <Chosen >
      <option >vanila</option>
      <option >strawberry</option>
      <option >chocolate</option>
    </Chosen>
    );
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <Example/>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### File *index.js*

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think when I wrap with `$()` in line 1 it becomes the jquery object. and we can call jquery method on that.

Comment: Hey @diEcho did you got any solution to this issue

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question more than once.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by following these steps (after creating a project using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) (executable `create-react-app`)):

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install chosen-js --save
```

Add this in line #1 of file *node_modules/chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js*

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45710645/1285397)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import $ from 'jquery'
import "chosen-js/chosen.css";
import "chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js";

class Chosen extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.chosen();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.$el.on('change', this.handleChange);
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    this.$el.off('change', this.handleChange);
    this.$el.chosen('destroy');
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="Chosen-select" style={{width: "200px"}} ref={el => this.el = el}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <Chosen className="chosen-container chosen-container-single" onChange={value => console.log(value)}>
      <option>vanilla</option>
      <option>chocolate</option>
      <option>strawberry</option>
    </Chosen>
  );
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          <Example/>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I made this way but my screen is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue while reading the documentation. But instead of updating the "**node_modules/chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js**" file, I prefer to Use the ProvidePlugin to inject implicit globals in *webpack.config.js*.

But when we created an application using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/), we didn't find the *webpack.config.js* file.
You will need to eject the React application. But you should first read from the following links before ejecting the application (if you’re a power user and you aren’t happy with the default configuration).

References:

- *[What happens when you eject Create React App?](https://github.com/satendra02/react-chrome-extension/wiki/What-happens-when-you-eject-Create-React-App)*
- *[Don’t eject your Create React App](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741)*

You will need to run the following command to eject the React application as this command will remove the single build dependency from your project and also copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies ([Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint), etc.) into your project as dependencies in file *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*.

> npm run eject

Install the dependencies

> npm install jquery chosen-js --save

Now edit your *webpack.config.js* file and update the configuration object as follows:

```
return {
    ...
    module: {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [
        ...
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
          }),
    ]
    ...
}
```

**Chosen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import "chosen-js/chosen.css";
import "chosen-js/chosen.jquery.js";

class Chosen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.chosen();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.$el.on("change", this.handleChange);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.children !== this.props.children) {
      this.$el.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$el.off("change", this.handleChange);
    this.$el.chosen("destroy");
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={(el) => (this.el = el)}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue related with a dependency.

I notice that you include jQuery and its chosen plugin with a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) which means it is declared globally. But in the third line of `App.js`, you `import $ from 'jquery';` which may introduce jQuery locally. In my experience, React will refer `$` to the local jQuery instance which is not with the plugin.

I suggest that you could try comment out `import $ from 'jquery'` and try again.

Comment: if I comment out `import $ from 'jquery'` ,  then it gives `'$' is not defined  no-undef` error

Comment: You need to include jquery core as well.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/core.js
Or use the official version if you want only one external link.
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Thank you for the useful prototype website but still it's not working. see the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7wr7jvx3z) . showing red squiggly underline at `$` in App.js . and also gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/core.js:5` in console

Comment: Just update the example. Errors gone. I used offical JQuery cdn instead.
https://codesandbox.io/s/91ow04loko

Comment: I followed the same you suggest but it still giving **Failed to compile** error in page `./src/App.js
  Line 15:  '$' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156544/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-fung).

Comment: I joined the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.$("#infomodal").modal("hide");
```